# SQLite Room Fast Insert JSON Array

Tags: android, json, sqlite, android-room

I'm creating a vocabulary app that loads words/definitions from a JSON file into a JSON array. Then I loop through the JSON array to load the data into a Room Database.

Based on the Log statements, the JSON array loads very quickly (probably at most 1-2 seconds) but the Room database takes much long to load in an asynchronous thread (around 40 seconds).

My MainActivity class tries the load a word from the database into the layout in onCreate but obviously the app crashes since the database hasn't finished loading yet.

What's the recommended way to solve this? FYI, the database is intended to only need to be created once and will only be read from after the first load.

My thoughts For Possible Solutions:

1) Use the JSONArray data the first time a user opens the app and then use the database after

2) Add a copy of the datafile file to the assets folder and access it from there (not sure how this would work with Room)

3) Maybe my code is inefficient and there's a faster way to load the Room DB?

```
private String fileName = "majortests_words.json";
private JSONArray wordBankAry;
Word currentWord = new Word();
int totalWords = 1000;
Random rand = new Random();
int currentWordIndex = 0;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    deleteDatabase("word-database");
    loadWords();
    DatabaseInitializer.populateAsync(AppDatabase.getAppDatabase(this), wordBankAry);

    currentWordIndex = rand.nextInt(totalWords);
    currentWord = AppDatabase.getAppDatabase(this).wordDao().getWord(currentWordIndex);

    // code to add attributes of currentWord to the layout

public String loadJSONData() {
    String jsonStr = null;
    try {
        InputStream iStream = getAssets().open(fileName);
        int size = iStream.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        iStream.read(buffer);
        iStream.close();

        jsonStr = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return jsonStr;
}

public void loadWords() {
    try {
        String jsonStr = loadJSONData();
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
        wordBankAry = jsonObj.getJSONArray("wordBank");
        totalWords = wordBankAry.length();
        Log.d("MainActivity", "JSON Count:" + wordBankAry.length());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

.

```
@Database(entities = {Word.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    private static AppDatabase INSTANCE;
    static String DB_NAME = "word-database";

    public abstract WordDao wordDao();

    public static AppDatabase getAppDatabase(Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, DB_NAME).allowMainThreadQueries().build();
    }
    return INSTANCE;
}

    public static void destroyInstance() {
        INSTANCE = null;
    }
}
```

.

```
@Dao
public interface WordDao {
    @Insert
    public void insertWords(Word word);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM words")
    List<Word> getAll();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM words WHERE id = :id")
    public Word getWord(int id);
}
```

.

```
public class DatabaseInitializer {

    private static final String TAG = DatabaseInitializer.class.getName();

    public static void populateAsync(@NonNull final AppDatabase db, JSONArray wordBankAry) {
        PopulateDbAsync task = new PopulateDbAsync(db, wordBankAry);
        task.execute();
    }

    public static Word addWord(final AppDatabase db, Word word) {
        db.wordDao().insertWords(word);
        return word;
    }

    private static void populateWordBank(AppDatabase db, JSONArray wordBankAry) {
        Word word = new Word();
        try {
            for (int wordIndex = 0; wordIndex < wordBankAry.length(); wordIndex++) {
                JSONObject jsonObj = wordBankAry.getJSONObject(wordIndex);
                word.setWordName(jsonObj.getString("word"));
                word.setWordDefinition(jsonObj.getString("definition"));

                addWord(db, word);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        List<Word> wordList = db.wordDao().getAll();
        Log.d(DatabaseInitializer.TAG, "Rows Count:" + wordList.size());
    }

    private static class PopulateDbAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private final AppDatabase mDb;

        private JSONArray mWordBankAry;

        PopulateDbAsync(AppDatabase db, JSONArray wordBankAry) {
            mDb = db;
            mWordBankAry = wordBankAry;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(final Void... params) {
            populateWordBank(mDb, mWordBankAry);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
@Entity(tableName = "words")
public class Word {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "word_name")
    private String wordName;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "word_definition")
    private String wordDefinition;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getWordName() {
        return wordName;
    }

    public void setWordName(String wordName) {
        this.wordName = wordName;
    }

    public String getWordDefinition() {
        return wordDefinition;
    }

    public void setWordDefinition(String wordDefinition) {
        this.wordDefinition = wordDefinition;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> What's the recommended way to solve this?

Replace this with a pre-packaged database. [`SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) can be used with Room, albeit not as cleanly as I would like. See [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-androidarch/tree/v0.6/General/AssetRoom) for a demonstration of the technique.

> Maybe my code is inefficient and there's a faster way to load the Room DB?

Right now, you are doing one database transaction per word. That will be slow. Instead, make a single `insert()` call, using an `@Insert` method that takes `List<Word>` or `Word[]` as a parameter. This should automatically wrap *all* of those inserts into a single transaction. One large transaction will be much more efficient than N little transactions.